# How can I make a table border work on all browsers?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I have a table with a border. Right now, the border works on Brave browser. On Chrome and Safari, the border extends out too far. If I make it smaller, the border ends before the `<td>`. Is there a way to make it so that it is only as long as the `<td>`? Sorry if this is really obvious I'm kind of new to this and couldn't find any information online. Right now I have:

```css
/* not much to show but this is what happens in Chrome/Safari */
table {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: ‘Jost’, sans-serif;
  border: 7px solid red;
  border-radius: 13px;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 8%;
  margin-left: 8%;
  border-spacing: 3px;
}
td {
  background-color: yellow
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: remove display:block

Answer (score 1):

From W3: 
Block - Displays an element as a block element (like

). It starts on a new line, and takes up the **whole width**.

Remove the display type:  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp